# How to define an aspect inside spring config using java configuration only

Tags: java, spring, annotations, aspectj, aspect

Here is an example of how you can define an aspect using annotations:

```
@Aspect
public class BlaBla() {
    @Pointcut(...)
    ...

    @Before(...)
    ...

    @After(...)
    ...
}
```

This is the only way that I found through research. However I want class BlaBla to not be polluted with annotations and pointcut methods. I want it to remain a POJO. If I were to use xml spring configuration, I could do it easily:

```
<bean id="blaBla" class="BlaBla">...</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="blaBla">
        <aop:pointcut .../>
        <aop:before .../>
        <aop:after .../>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

However, I am not using xml configuration, but a Java configuration instead. Basically question is, how can I say to spring that class BlaBla is an aspect without changing BlaBla class itself, but instead to define it inside a java class annotated with `@Configuration` spring annotation.

Comment: The main principle of AOP ist to modularise a cross-cutting concern - called an aspect - in one place like you would modularise a core concern into a class. Why do you want to tear it apart at all? I never understood that approach. You first code example says it all: "This is an aspect BlaBla, containing the following pointcuts and advice etc." What you want just does not make sense IMO. Maintain aspect-related stuff in an aspect, not separately from it. Why search in two places when trying to understand the aspect logic?

Comment: Because BlaBla is a bean also. I theoretically could want to use it as aspect for one set of interfaces and at the same time inject it in some other class and use it in a different way. In this case I would not want for my bean to have a public pointcut method because it may not belong to what this object is about in a business sense. It also just seems more decoupled to me personally. As if I will be safer. What if later I decide to use BlaBla through non-aop way. In this case I would just remove configurations and not touch it at all.

Comment: I am not buying your arguments, but good luck to you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make another class BlaBlaAopConfig or something like that which will be your configuration class.

Java config is not different from xml, you need to define it and you should do it seperate from your code. Only difference you get, while using java config over xml is better (or worse depending on personal preferences) clarity. But you never want to mix aop and pojo code in one class.

You will define in @Pointcut your target class BlaBla

Comment: I understand this, but in this case BlaBlaAopConfig becomes aspect of itself? So it is an aspect that delegates before and after methods to a bean of BlaBla. Isn't this different from making BlaBla aspect?
In other words, in the xml example I provided, BlaBla is an aspect.
The example which you provide, makes BlaBlaAopConfig an aspect that delegates to BlaBla which is a pojo. What I wanted is a code equivalent of xml config in a way that I want to declare in SpringConfig.java the fact that BlaBla _is an_ aspect. But at the same time to not touch the BlaBla class and leave it as POJO.

Comment: Well it doesnt make any sense. BlaBla is POJO and it shouldn't be an aspect itself. Code equivalent of xml is exactly my solution. In xml you have got just reference to object which you would do in @Pointcut in BlaBlaAopConfig. You have two **seperate** xml tags, one for bean one for aop and java config is just way to writing config in java so you need exactly the same thing!

Comment: After some thinking I realized that I'm too strict about it. You are right.